# Cannot build Gridsome project: modal causes 'window is not defined' error

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, gridsome

My project runs ok in development mode but fails in build mode. The full error is

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/vue-js-modal/dist/index.js:1:210)
at __webpack_require__ (webpack/bootstrap:25:0)
at Module.<anonymous> (assets/js/app.a0a1f9b3.js:5157:12)
at __webpack_require__ (webpack/bootstrap:25:0)
at Object.<anonymous> (assets/js/app.a0a1f9b3.js:2785:18)
at __webpack_require__ (webpack/bootstrap:25:0)
at assets/js/app.a0a1f9b3.js:118:18
at Object.<anonymous> (assets/js/app.a0a1f9b3.js:121:10)
at o (/home/nestor/progs/gridsome_blog/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:77545)
at /home/nestor/progs/gridsome_blog/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:78138
```

The only clue that gives me is the modal plugin. I've read that it's because of client side rendering but don't understand how to fix it in this case. In `main.js` I import and set the plugin with:

```
import VModal from 'vue-js-modal'
// other things
Vue.use(VModal, { dynamic: true , dynamicDefaults: { clickToClose: true }, injectModalsContainer: true})
```

and I use it in a `vue` file as a dynamic modal, so when a button is clicked the modal is created by a method defined in the export dictionary:

```
export default {
     // other things
     methods:{ show_modal(title_,company_,url_,text_){
          this.$modal.show({
            template: `
            <div id="modal_div" style="padding: 0px; overflow: auto;">
              <h4 id="#modal_title" style="margin:15px;">{{title}}</h4>
              <a target="_blank" :href="url"> <h5 id="#modal_subtitle" style="margin:15px;">{{company}}</h5></a>
              <p id="#modal_text" style="margin:15px;font-family:Muli;text-align:justify">{{text}}</p>
            </div>
              `,
              props: ['title','company','url','text']
            }, {
              title: title_,
              company: 'With: ' + company_,
              url: url_,
              text: text_
            }, {
              height: 'auto',
              adaptive: true,
              draggable: true
            }, {
              'before-close': (event) => { console.log('modal closed'); }
            })
    }
}
```

I'm new with Vue, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, this is because [SSR](https://gridsome.org/docs/assets-scripts/#without-ssr-support) - there is no `window` during build. One way is to use `<ClientOnly>` tags in your template and make all this things in `mounted()` in export.

In this particular case you are lucky: there's a [plugin](https://gridsome.org/plugins/gridsome-plugin-modal) for your component. Gridsome plugin library contains many wrappers for vue components, so you can use them easier.

Comment: You're right, after importing `'vue-js-modal/dist/ssr.index'` instead, and including the plugin you mention, it worked.